# The version of node the terminal says im running is different from the version when running the command node -v

Tags: node.js, reactjs, npm, npx

when creating a new react app (i.e. npx create-react-app ecommerce) its says im running Node 12.22.1 and Create React App requires Node 14 or higher. However, when i run node -v it says im running v16.17.0. does anyone know how to fix this?

Comment: What operating system and npm version? Are you using anything like `nvm`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try `npx -p node@16 create-react-app ecommerce`